# Compare current polydata cell with next cell - VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

Little bit confused on how to compare current polydata cell with next.

Example for plain simple c++ comparison, but I don't really get how I can get it with polydata

```
for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
        //compare i cell with j cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: What property of the cells do you want to compare?

Comment: triangle cells, basically problem is iteration, not the comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following approaches:

```
pd // a polydata
polys = pd->GetPolys();
vtkCellArray* polys2= vtkCellArray::New();
polys2->DeepCopy(polys);

size = polys->GetNumberOfCells();

vtkIdList* Ids = vtkIdList::New();
vtkIdList* Ids2 = vtkIdList::New();
for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
    polys->GetNextCell(Ids);
    for(j = 1; j < size; j++){
        polys2->GetNextCell(Ids2);
        //compare i cell with j cell)
    }
}
```

or this should also work (but might be less efficient):

```
pd // a polydata
polys = pd->GetPolys();

size = polys->GetNumberOfCells();

vtkIdList* Ids = vtkIdList::New();
vtkIdList* Ids2 = vtkIdList::New();
for(i = 0; i < size-1; i++){
    polys->GetNextCell(Ids);
    for(j = 1; j < size; j++){
        polys2->GetCell(j,Ids2);
        //compare i cell with j cell)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :), i already figured out bit differently with traversals, but yours looks great